# char pointer in C initialized with string — can anyone explain to me each step

Tags: c, pointers

```
const char var = '1'; // or var = 'a'
```

I have written these two lines
in Xcode 5.1.1, Command line tool--> select C

```
const  char * stmt_sel = "select * from Student";

printf("sql : %s",stmt_sel);
```

I'm confused: `char` accepts single `char`, `char` pointer accepting string.
Can anyone explain to me about the pointer in clear and how it works in this scenario?

Comment: Fundamentally, this is basic text book material.  The `char *stmt_sel` points to both a single character `s` and also to the start of an array of characters terminated by a null byte (the select statement).  It is up to the programmer to decide which is the correct interpretation at any given time.  The `%s` format expects a character pointer that points to (the start of) a null-terminated array of characters.

Comment: What is the relevance of `var` to your question?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think the OP mentioned `var` since he/she was confused why `char` accpets a single character, while `char *` accepts a `string`. Hence, he gave an example of both.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` pointer can point to a string, but it does not store it.

When you do this

```
const char *stmt_sel = "select * from Student";
```

`stmt_sel` contains the address of the memory location where the string is stored<sup>1</sup>, the type of the pointer allows pointer arithmetic to work, for example

```
printf("%s\n", stmt_sel + 7);
```

would print `* from Student`, because you moved the pointer 7 units of it's type size, and since `sizeof(char) == 1`, then that means 7 bytes.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'ts not a physical address, it's a virtual address used by the operating system and in the end it gets mapped to a hardware address.</sub>